# how to detect if background music is playing in windows phone 8.1 (universal app)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, audio-player

Hi I'm developing a simple background player app in windows phone 8.1 (no silverlight), so I can figure out how can detect if other music is playing...

Xna is gone... and Mediaplayer or background player do not have such kind of method or property.

So can I achieve this thing...

thanks

Comment: Have you tried [BackgroundMediaPlayer.IsMediaPlaying](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer.ismediaplaying.aspx)?

Comment: yes seems to works, but is difficult to detect because if even stopped the other player seems to report true calling  BackgroundMediaPlayer.IsMediaPlaying