# How to detect if another application's audio is playing in background? (UWP, Windows 10)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, naudio, wasapi

I am writing a C# SDK (to be used by UWP Publishers) and would like to detect if another application (Pandora, Spotify, Amazon Music, etc.) is playing music in the background, so that I can mute my SDK's sounds.

[This comment to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830714/how-to-detect-if-background-music-is-playing-in-windows-phone-8-1-universal-app) seems to indicate that I can use  BackgroundMediaPlayer.IsMediaPlaying(), but when I play Pandora in a web browser, or the Amazon Music App, this method seems to always return false when music is playing in another app.

[This answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034205/how-to-detect-if-another-audio-is-playing-in-background-windows-phone-7) seems to indicate that we used to be able to use Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer.State to detect if another app was playing background music, but I don't believe this call is not available in UWP (please let me know if I'm wrong -- I mainly care about this working on Desktop and XBox One).

So my question is, how can I determine if another app (on desktop or in web browser or on Windows phone) is playing music?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `BackgroundMediaPlayer.IsMediaPlaying` detects audio playing from WinRT/UWP apps only and not Win32 apps. This API was important for apps on Mobile because you were only allowed to have one app with background audio at any given time. I don't think there is a way to detect this for Win32 apps at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The `BackgroundMediaPlayer.IsMediaPlaying` method is now obsolete. I've noticed that if background music is playing in UWP, calls to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer.Play` succeed but do not actually play any music, so it seems the check is not necessary in some cases.